How do I move a type to a dependent assembly without breaking deserialzation of existing data?
I have a .Net framework project that contains two different concerns:
( This is a cut down illustration of the real problem space )
CompanyName.ProjectName
  /consumers
  /DTOs

I want to split out the /DTOs into a different project:
CompanyName.ProjectName
  /consumers
CompanyName.ProjectName.Dtos
  /DTOs

So that I can easily convert the DTOs to use .NET Standard 2.0, so they can be consumed elsewhere by .Net8 projects.
The Consumers part relies on Framework, so converting the whole project is not at this time an option.
I can move over the DTOs to a different project and the build works.
However we have historical data serialized with the type information in the JSON such as:
{
  "$type": "CompanyName.Project.Namespace.Item, CompanyName.ProjectName",
  ...


If I try to move out the DTOs to a different project, then even if I maintain the namespace, the deserialisation breaks, because it can't find NameSpace.Item in assembly CompanyName.ProjectName.
Question:
Is there a way to compile a dependency such that the types are found in the parent project assembly?
Alternatively, is there something I do to alter the behaviour of NewtonSoft.Json type handling to also look in the new assembly for the type?

wild guess, but maybe TypeForwardedTo

That does look useful, but wouldn't that require referencing the framework assembly from the standard assembly, something I'm unable to do?

I'll probably end up maintaining shallow copies of the types in the original assembly and just inherit from the new classes if there's no better or cleaner solution.

This is one reason I prefer System.Text.Jsons approach with explicit typeDescriminators. So if switching serialization libraries is an option you could just add a JsonDerivedType attribute with the old typeDiscriminator.

@Eterm I don't think so ,you are forwarding to it (not from it). I don't have the setup, but a quick test might reveal if it's feasible at all.

Is the type needed to deserialize the json?

You can create a custom SerializationBinder, override BindToType(), and remap the assembly names.  See e.g. this answer by Jeff to Serializing in Azure Function or this answer by Ross Jones to Handling namespace changes with TypeNameHandling.All.  Does that answer your question?

Using a custom serialization binder is advantageous for another reason: it mitigates the risk of type injection attacks.  See e.g. TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json and External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?.

In case the types being moved to a different assembly are deeply nested inside generics, the BindToType() method from this answer by Olivier to How to create a SerializationBinder for the Binary Formatter that handles the moving of types from one assembly and namespace to another should be usable.  (It's for binary formatter but the Json.NET binder has the same API shape.)

Thanks @dbc, I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on. Is that something you'd like to type up as a full answer?
